# Why does Java type inference fail to distinguish between Function and Consumer?

Tags: java, functional-programming

Given the following identity functions:

```
<T> Consumer<T> f(Consumer<T> c) { return c; }          // (1)
<T,R> Function<T,R> f(Function<T, R> c) { return c; }   // (2)
```

I observe the following behaviour in JDK 11 and JDK 17:

```
void _void() {}
f(x -> {});                   // okay, dispatches to (1)
f(x -> { return; });          // okay, dispatches to (1)
f(x -> { _void(); });         // okay, dispatches to (1)
f(x -> _void());              // should dispatch to (1)
|  Error:
|  reference to f is ambiguous
|    both method f(java.util.function.Function<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>) in  
     and method f(java.util.function.Consumer<java.lang.Object>) in  match

int _one() { return 1; }
f(x -> 1);                    // okay, dispatches to (2)
f(x -> { return 1; });        // okay, dispatches to (2)
f(x -> { return _one(); });   // okay, dispatches to (2)
f(x -> _one());               // should dispatch to (2)
|  Error:
|  reference to f is ambiguous
|    both method <T,R>f(java.util.function.Function<T,R>) in
     and method <T>f(java.util.function.Consumer<T>) in  match
```

Why can't the compiler resolve these symbols by using the return type of the expression? The curly brace versions work fine, and I would have thought they would be the more difficult cases. I understand that you can explicity cast the lambda function, but that defeats the purpose of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: It’s worth noting that the compiler emits this warning: `warning: [overloads] <T#1>f(Consumer<T#1>) in FunctionRecognitionTest is potentially ambiguous with <T#2,R>f(Function<T#2,R>) in FunctionRecognitionTest`

Comment: So the question is why the compiler doesn't manage to resolve the conflict by looking at the return type of the invoked statement. Right?

Comment: @ernest_k yes, that's correct, i updated the question to be more clear

Comment: Method signatures don't include return type.

Comment: @NathanHughes, Java doesn't dispatch on return types, but in this case I'm referring to the return type of the functional interface used to implement the lambda. The two possibilities are: `R Function.apply(T t)` and `void Consumer.accept(T t)`

Comment: The return type is not part of a function signature. You can't define two functions with the same name/parameters even if they return a different type. For the same reason the compiler is unable to understand if you want to use the consumer or the function (except for the return type, they have the same signature)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x -> _void()` and `x -> one()` are expected to be compatible with `Consumer<T>` (with the result of `one()` to be discarded).

When the lambda body is of a block type, the compiler additionally checks the "return" compatibility.
The [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2) is rather explicit about void/value compatibility for block bodies:

> A block lambda body is void-compatible if every return statement in the block has the form **return;**.
> A block lambda body is value-compatible if it cannot complete normally (§14.21) and every return statement in the block has the form **return Expression;**.

While that doesn't say why the single-expression bodies fail, it says exactly why block bodies compile: the compiler looks at the `return` forms to judge on those bodies' compatibility with `Consumer` or `Function` (in this case).

For the method invocation expressions, the fact that this is allowed:

```
Consumer<Integer> c = x -> one(); //discarded result
Function<T, Integer> f = x -> one(); //returned result
```

doesn't enable the compiler to resolve the conflict that you observed. You can rewrite the same lambda expression with block bodies to resolve the conflict, and that's simply because block bodies are checked differently, by spec.

---

I guess I'm trying to say that the more natural question is *"why block bodies compile at all in this case"*, given that we normally don't expect return types (forms?) to participate in overload resolution. But lambda expressions' congruence with types is something else, isn't it...  I think *this* (that block type helps target type inference) is the special behavior.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR:

The cases that fail to compile, fail to compile because of two main reasons:

- the lambdas have a statement expression (a method call in this case) as their bodies, making them compatible with both the `Consumer<T>` and `Function<T, R>` overloads,
- the lambdas are also implicitly typed, making them not pertinent to applicability, so overload resolution is unable to decide between the overloads.

---

Let's go through the [overload resolution steps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) in the spec to see where exactly this fails :)

First, let's determine the *potentially applicable methods*. For both `x -> _void()` and `x -> _one()`, both overloads are potentially applicable. This is because both lambda expressions are [*congruent*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3) to the function types of both `Function<T, R>` and `Consumer<T>`. The important condition is:

> If the lambda parameters are assumed to have the same types as the
> function type's parameter types, then:
>
> - If the function type's result is void, the lambda body is either a statement expression (§14.8) or a void-compatible block.
> - If the function type's result is a (non-void) type R, then either i) the lambda body is an expression that is compatible with R in an
>   assignment context, or ii) the lambda body is a value-compatible block, and each result expression (§15.27.2) is compatible with R in an assignment context.

(Also notice that for the cases that compile, exactly one of the methods is potentially applicable.)

Then we try to resolve the method to invoke using [strict invocation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.2). Loose and variable arity invocation are not very relevant here, so if this phase fails, the whole thing fails. Notice that at the start of that section, the spec defines "pertinent to applicability", and both `x -> _void()` and `x -> _one()` are not pertinent to applicability. This will be important.

We then reach:

> If m is a generic method and the method invocation does not provide explicit type arguments, then the applicability of the method is inferred as specified in [§18.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.1).

According to §18.5.1, to determine the applicability of a method wrt to a call, you first add inference bounds according to the arguments and type parameters. Then you [reduce](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.2) and [incorporate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.3) the bounds. If there are no *false* bounds (which are produced when you have conflicting bounds) in the result, then the method is applicable. The relevant point here is that arguments that are not pertinent to applicability are not considered when adding those bounds:

> To test for applicability by strict invocation:
>
> If k ≠ n, or if there exists an i (1 ≤ i ≤ n) such that ei is
> pertinent to applicability (§15.12.2.2) and either i) ei is a
> standalone expression of a primitive type but Fi is a reference type,
> or ii) Fi is a primitive type but ei is not a standalone expression of
> a primitive type; then the method is not applicable and there is no
> need to proceed with inference.
>
> Otherwise, C includes, for all i (1 ≤ i ≤ k) where ei is pertinent to
> applicability, ‹ei → Fi θ›.

So the only bounds that are added are those from the type parameters. They obviously are not going to disagree/conflict with each other and produce a *false* bound, since they are independent.

So again, both methods are *applicable*.

When there are more than one applicable method, we of course choose the most specific method. The process for doing this for generic methods is described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.4). It's quite long so I won't quote it here. In principle, it is similar to how §18.5.1 works - add some type bounds, if they agree with each other (no *false*), then one method is more specific than the other. In this case, however, the implicitly typed lambdas cause a *false* bound to be added :(

---

Now knowing this, you can basically make it work the way you want by using explicitly typed lambdas, which are pertinent to applicability.

```
f((Integer x) -> _one()); // (2)
f((Integer x) -> _void()); // (1)
```